# Create a simple CoreOS cluster on 4 machines

Tags: coreos

I'd like to try out coreos on our little cluster (4 machines). I’d like to install coreos on each machine’s disk.

I’ve got a trusty64 live cd that I will use to run the coreos-install script. Is there a default cloud-config file I could use to set this up ?

I want to give each machine the private ip 192.168.5.i

Would this file be enough to init my cluster when installing coreos on disk on my first machine (192.168.5.1) ? http://pastie.org/private/njub0e4nahb10enh9nnw

```
#cloud-config
ssh_authorized_keys:
  - ssh-rsa MYKEY
coreos:
  etcd:
    discovery: https://discovery.etcd.io/MYTOKEN
    addr: 192.168.5.1:4001
    peer-addr: 192.168.5.1:7001
  fleet:
    public-ip: 192.168.5.1
  units:
    - name: etcd.service
      command: start
    - name: fleet.service
      command: start
```

Seems like when installing on disk $private_ipv4 is not interpreted (do I have to enter the ip then ?)

Answer (score 1):

For bare metal, you'll need to set up static networking with a network unit.

More info here: https://coreos.com/docs/cluster-management/setup/network-config-with-networkd/#static-networking

Comment: I read this doc but did not really understand what is needed. As I have a  small number of machines, is that possible to describe all the nodes (name, ip,...) in the same cloud-config file ? Otherwise, when installing CoreOS on each node (bare metal), my understanding is that a network file needs to be set on each node, is that correvt

Comment: Can this be done after coreos is installed ? What could be a minimal cloud-config file ? Thanks a lot for your help Rob.